# Best practices for second hard drive on macOS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssh, storage

I’ve a 1TB Mac Mini (Seagate hybrid HD + SSD) but I’m running out of space so I bought a second drive (Samsung 860 EVO 1TB).

Since it is as large as the first hard drive I don’t think using fusion drive would be a good idea and since the new drive is faster I think I should make it my boot drive, but how should I integrate the two to make the best of the new speed storage?

I’m thinking of migrating my user account to the new drive and keep iTunes Library, Photos Library and iMovie Library in the old drive. This 3 libraries are my main storage hogs. If that’s all, I think I don’t even need hard links.

Any additional tips and suggestions?

Comment: This question probably needs to be reworded somewhat so it's not going to get closed as being primarily opinion-based. I'd suggest you refocus it to ask a specific *How to...* question and include your exact model of Mac mini and the connections/ports of your new Samsung drive.

Answer (score 1):

Internal or external? Which (exact model) of Mac Mini? Without that info this answert is gonna be vague.

If it is an external SSD connected via USB-C/Thunderbolt. you could do what I did, install masOS on the external and boot from it and then use migration utility to move everything to the external SSD and used the old internal drive for incidental storage and as an "emergency" boot drive.

If it is a slower interface I would benchmark your current setup. Install your OS and files on the external and benchmark it again, then decide how to configure it.

Depending on what is in your user folder in the way of files (what kind, text, graphics, video, music) and how much you use it you could keep your user folder on on the slower drive. Mostly text docs, PDFs and the like should be no problem, but if you are editing a lot of video or graphics that is I/O intensive, keep your files on the faster drive.

If you are installing a second **internal** drive I would pretty much do it the same way. An internal SSD would be *really fast* and you would get full benefit of the speed on the internal bus. I'd put everything on the SSD.